# PostGIS S3 Out-DB raster: Cannot open offline raster

Tags: postgis, gdal, postgresql, raster2pgsql

I want to import and query a GeoTIFF stored in an Amazon S3 bucket via PostGIS as an out-DB raster.
The file was imported via raster2pgsql using GDAL's Virtual File Systems interface, i.e.

`raster2pgsql ... -R /vsis3/mybucket/mytiff.tif | psql ...`

PostGIS settings:

| name | setting |
| --- | --- |
| postgis.enable_outdb_rasters | on |
| postgis.gdal_enabled_drivers | ENABLE_ALL |
| postgis.gdal_vsi_options | AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XYZ AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=123 |

The import succeeded and I can access the out-DB-metadata saved in the table, such as

`SELECT ST_ENVELOPE(rast) FROM mytable`.

However any query on the actual raster data (e.g. ST_VALUE) fails with

```
SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: rt_band_load_offline_data: Cannot open offline raster: /vsis3/mybucket/mytiff.tif
```

When I ran into this problem with out-DB tifs located on my machine, it was usually a path or permissions issue. Any ideas what the issue with an file on S3 might be?

Versions:

| name | v |
| --- | --- |
| OS | Win 10 Pro |
| Postgresql | PostgreSQL 14.7, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit |
| PostGIS | 3.2 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1 |
| GDAL | GDAL 3.5.3, |

Comment: Do you got the answer already? I got the same issue as you describe above. After looking the answer from various source, I still do not have idea why the issue happened

Comment: I have the same problem on a Windows 10 localhost PostGIS instance. All GDAL drivers and postgis_raster out-db are enabled. The rasters are in my user directory, so a permission issue would be very surprising...